# Why doesn't Django's `full_clean` work when using a non-default database?

Tags: django, database, orm

*Note, this is a rewrite of a deleted question.  I'd have edited it, but there were no comments, so I never even knew it was deleted until I went to add new details today.*

*Background*: I'm modifying our code-base to make use of multiple databases for validation of user-submitted load files.  This is for automated checks of that user data so that they can fix simple issues with their files, like checks on uniqueness and such.

Our original code (not written by me) has some fundamental issues with loading.  It had side-effects.  It should have used `transaction.atomic`, but didn't and simply adding it broke the codebase, so while a refactor will eventually fix that properly, to reduce effort...

*Question*: I created a second database (with the alias "validation") and inserted `.using(db)` and `.save(using=db)` in all the necessary places in our code, so that loading data can be tested without risking the production data.

Everything works as expected with the 2 databases except calls to `full_clean()`.  Take this example:

```py
new_compound_dict = {
    name="test",
    formula="C1H4",
    hmdb_id="HMBD0000001",
}
new_compound = Compound(**new_compound_dict)
new_compound.full_clean()
new_compound.save(using="validation")
```

It gives me this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'name': ['Compound with this Name already exists.'], 'hmdb_id': ['Compound with this HMDB ID already exists.']}
```

I get the same error with this code:

```py
new_compound, inserted = Compound.objects.using("validation").get_or_create(**new_compound_dict)
if inserted:
    new_compound.full_clean()
```

Both examples above work without a problem on the `default` database.

I looked up `full_clean` in the docs for django 3.2, but I don't see a way to have it run against a database other than `default`, which I'm assuming is what I would need to do to fix this.  There's not even a mention of any potential issues related to a non-default database that I can find.  I had expected the doc to show that there's a `using` parameter to `full_clean` (like the one for `.save(using=db)`), but there's no such parameter.

I debugged the above examples with this before and after each example block:

```py
Compound.objects.using("default").filter(**new_compound_dict).count()
Compound.objects.using("validation").filter(**new_compound_dict).count()
```

For the default database, the counts are 0 before and 1 after with no error.  For the validation database, the counts are 0 and 1, but *with* the error mentioned above.

At this point, I'm confounded.  How can I run `full_clean` on a database other than the default?  Does full_clean just fundamentally not support non-default databases?

*Footnote: The compound loading data in the example above is never validated in a user submission.  It is necessary that the compound data be in both databases in order to validate the data submitted by the user, so the compound load script is one of 2 scripts that loads data into both databases (so that it's in the validation DB when the user submits their data).  The default load always happens before the validation load and when I load the validation database, the test compound is always present in the default database and is only present after the validation load in the validation database.*

Comment: The original question was at least a couple months old and I'm now actually about 2 or 3 weeks into the ultimate refactor that rewrites the loading scripts that uses atomic transactions. (They have to have a bunch of other features as well to support the "user data validation interface" which involves a lot of code.) But the version using the validation database has been working sufficiently using a work-around that simply doesn't call `full_clean` when the database being loaded is the validation database. That's 31 instances of calls to full clean in the codebase.

Comment: I updated the question because it just irks me when I don't understand what the problem is. I'm doing the "better" refactor (i.e. introducing atomic transactions) in phases, & I haven't yet extricated the validation db, so I've been discovering little bugs here & there - like an override of save in 1 model that needed a `.using(db)` in a db operation, so I've been making quick fixes to the validation DB in order to get tests to pass at the end of each phase. And in making such edits, I re-encountered the `full_clean`-associated ValidationErrors (e.g. when changing to using `get_or_create`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to helpful user Ken Whitesell in the [Django Forum](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/why-cant-i-call-full-clean-on-data-bound-for-a-non-default-database/18947):

> the unique test for a model is performed using the Model._default_manager.

His suggestions:

> you would probably be able to create a custom manager that checks for a specific attribute on a model instance if that instance is to be used with a non-default database.

> You might also be able to use a custom router to check an instance, if the function being used provides the [instance “hint”](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/#hints) to the router.

So as I had suspected, you cannot (without custom code), run `full_clean` using a non-default database in Django (at least in 3.2.x).

I don't have a full answer for getting this to work, but I no longer need to because I'm near the end of the `transaction.atomic` refactor to correct the underlying problem that prompted me to use a second database in the first place.  During that refactor (early on), I'd re-encountered this issue, and simply wanted to edify myself on this issue because I hate not understanding why something isn't working that seems like it should.